# Change Ubuntu time and date for specific application

Tags: 16.04, time, date

Is there any application which can manipulate time and date for any specific application? If I change date and time of system then browser can't let me access internet. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of, and why would you need that?

Comment: @MichaelBay That's not a helpful comment. Linux is very customizable and it's perfectly possible to do what Mihir wants to do.

Comment: @UTF-8 It wasn't meant to be helpful in the way you think. First, I'm not aware of any way to it. If you do then perhaps you should post an answer. **The help I gave was by *questioning* the purpose of that.** Why? Because I suspect this is another X-Y problem -or- something fishy like an attempt to circumvent some time limited software.

Comment: @MichaelBay I'm currently writing my answer. It takes some time because I'm currently doing other stuff as well and I want it to be a good one which teaches OP something as OP seems to be new to Linux.

Comment: @Mihir I'm sorry. I misread your question. My answer solves a different problem. I deleted it and will write another one which (hopefully) will tackle the problem you actually have.

Comment: @MichaelBay What OP does with the answers he gets here is none of your business. He doesn't need to explain what purpose he's planning to use it for. I don't want to answer such questions each time I ask or buy something, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `faketime` to tell processes it's a different time.

Install it via:

```
sudo apt install faketime
```

Then just run your application like this:

```
faketime -f '-5d' date
```

This calls `date`. So just substitute `date` with whatever you like.

The example goes 5 days back change that part to whatever you like.

If you want to learn more about how you can use `faketime`, check out its man page:

```
man faketime
```

Note that this only works after you installed it.

If you're curious how to achieve this for an application you launch from the Dash, check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/953439/195768).