# Running, or "injecting" software with specific date

Tags: time

Is there a package or a way to run a software with a specific date or time so that when you run it, it uses the date you input instead of your system date.

Comment: Start with a Virtual Machine, then destroy the VM's time synchronization mechanism. Since you didn't say which Ubuntu release you are using, that's as detailed as I'll get.

Comment: Probably dupe: [Change Ubuntu time and date for specific application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953429/change-ubuntu-time-and-date-for-specific-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`faketime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/faketime.1.html) command does exactly this.

```
$ date
Wed Nov 18 16:10:38 EST 2020
$ faketime 'next week' date
Wed Nov 25 16:10:42 EST 2020
$ faketime '1970-01-01 7:30 UTC' date
Thu Jan  1 02:30:00 EST 1970
```

By default, programs run with `faketime` still experience the passage of time in the usual way, just starting at whatever time you specify.

```
$ faketime '2004-10-20 11:06:23 CDT' bash -c 'for i in {1..5}; do date; sleep 1; done'
Wed Oct 20 12:06:23 EDT 2004
Wed Oct 20 12:06:24 EDT 2004
Wed Oct 20 12:06:25 EDT 2004
Wed Oct 20 12:06:26 EDT 2004
Wed Oct 20 12:06:27 EDT 2004
```

Those examples are with the `date` command for purposes of illustration, but `faketime` will run whatever command you specify.